# Filtering DateTime in IQueryable Result

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an application that is displaying a list of users on a page. The client has an option to filter the users. In my repository, I have a Linq query that returns an IQueryable of User. I am applying the filter and paging to the IQueryable result and calling the .ToList(). I have not been able to get the date filtering to work properly. It does not return anything if I include the "/" as part of a date search. For example, I have a patient with DOB 07/10/2000. It returns the patient when I type "07" but nothing if I type "07/". What changes can I make to the below query, without calling .ToList() before paging, to get the date filtering to work correct?

```
  IQueryable<User> users = _db.Users.Where(x => x.UserID == userID && x.Active == true);

  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param.filterValue))
            {
                users = users.Where(x => x.firstName.ToLower().Contains(param.filterValue.ToLower())
                 || x.lastName.ToLower().Contains(param.filterValue.ToLower())
                 || x.dateOfBirth.ToString().Contains(param.filterValue.ToLower())
                );
            }
```

**Updated 08/17/2018**

dateOfBirth is a DateTime field. However, the time is being ignored. The param.filterValue is an instance of the Parameters class shown below. It contains the value that is entered in the search box.

```
public class Parameters
{
    public int MAX_PAGE_SIZE {
        get {
            return 100;
        }
    }
    public string filterValue { get; set; }
    public int PageIndex { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
}
```

Also, I try it with this change.

```
x.dateOfBirth.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy").Contains(param.filterValue.ToLower())
```

It throws an exception

*`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`*

Comment: If `dateOfBirth` is `DateTime`, then you need to compare it as `DateTime` (e.g. convert `filterValue` to a `DataTime` and use a equals comparison

Comment: share us the value of `x.dateOfBirth` and `param.filterValue`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke the only issue is that the filterValue is being used for all the other fields as well. Furthermore, converting it to a date and use equal comparison will not allow for partial date filter. The other option that I am considering is to create a store procedure, and I can do the filtering and paging in the store procedure.

Comment: You add another variable (say `DateTime? date;` and use `DateTime.TryParse(param.filterValue, out date);` - the if `date` is not `null` its a valid date, so you use that - i.e. `.Where(x.dateOfBirth == date)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change you code like below:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchString))
        {
            users = users.Where(s => s.LastName.ToLower().Contains(SearchString.ToLower())
                  || s.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(SearchString.ToLower())
                  || s.DateOfBirth.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy").Contains(SearchString.ToLower()));
        }
```

Converts the value of the current DateTime object to its equivalent short date string representation.

**Update**:
`s.DateOfBirth.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` is supported in `EntityFrameworkCore`, it seems you are using `EntityFramework` which is only support `s.DateOfBirth.ToString()` after `EF 6.1`. Before `EF 6.1`, it even not support `s.DateOfBirth.ToString`.

For a workaround, try to change `IQueryable` to `AsEnumerable`.

```
            var users = db.Product.AsEnumerable();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filterValue))
        {
            users = users.Where(x => 

              x.CreationTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
              .Contains(filterValue.ToLower()));                 

        }
        var result = users.ToList();
```

Comment: when I did s.DateOfBirth.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), it threw an exception - LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression..

Comment: What is `users`? Could not reproduce your issue with `_context.Product.Where(p => p.CreationTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy").Contains("08/17/2018")).ToList();`

Comment: users is an IQueryable of user. If I call a .ToList() on users and apply the filter after, it works fine. It only does not work when I apply it to the IQueryable users.

Comment: Is your project asp.net core? I could not reproduce your issue. Share us the complete code.

Comment: @JeanB It seems you are using `EntityFramework`, try the update solution

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this exception because not all the c# functions can be converted to database level functions by EF Core.

c#'s ToLower() is not allowed on a db column in EFCore.

"users is an IQueryable of user. If I call a .ToList() on users and apply the filter after, it works fine. It only does not work when I apply it to the IQueryable users" -> It is happening because of IQueryable. In case of IQueryable, filters are applied on database itself before records are fetched in memory. Calling ToList() on IQueryable, fetches the records in memory and it becomes an IEnumerable.

If you are using Microsoft SQL Server for your database purpose, then you can check out the following [DbFunctions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctions?view=efcore-3.1) defined by Microsoft.

For first name and last name filter you can write like

```
users.Where(x => EF.Functions.Contains(x.firstName, param.filterValue.ToLower())
             || EF.Functions.Contains(x.lastName), param.filterValue.ToLower())
            );
```

Regarding the x.dateOfBirth, not sure why are you converting the Datetime field to string and then calling  Contains function. If it is already NVarchar or Varchar data type in your database then you can do same as firstName/lastName

```
EF.Functions.Contains(x.dateOfBirth, param.filterValue.ToLower())
```

or if it is date time then you can parse param.filterValue to Datetime and use any EF.DateDiff() function from the above given url.

You can define your own custom DbFunctions also, refer to this [post](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/add-custom-database-functions-for-entity-framework-core)